# Why the association attribute inside ActiveRecord model cannot be updated without `self`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have defined a model **Item** which is subclass of `ActiveRecord::Base`
It has a association attribute called buyer which is a **member**

It has a buy method to update the buyer attribute.

```
# do buy transaction on that item
def buy(people_who_buy, amount)
  buyer = people_who_buy
  save
  ....
end
```

This code cannot update the buyer attribute. The sql generate only do sql selection of member from the database.

But after I add `self.` before `buyer` , it works fine.

```
# do buy transaction on that item
def buy(people_who_buy, amount)
  self.buyer = people_who_buy
  save
  ....
end
```

It looks weird!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `self.write_accessor` is required when calling a write_accessor, while in `self.read_accessor` the `self` can be omitted (and usually is avoided to keep the code a clean as possible).

---

From the [community-edited ruby styleguide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide):

> Avoid self where not required. (It is only required when calling a
>   self write accessor.)
>
> ```
> # bad
> def ready?
>   if self.last_reviewed_at > self.last_updated_at
>     self.worker.update(self.content, self.options)
>     self.status = :in_progress
>   end
>   self.status == :verified
> end
>
> # good
> def ready?
>   if last_reviewed_at > last_updated_at
>     worker.update(content, options)
>     self.status = :in_progress
>   end
>   status == :verified
> end
> ```

Comment: thanks for your answer and example :) is it one of the way to prevent from name conflict. say, the parameter is called buyer, i can do `self.buyer = buyer`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't just an ActiveRecord issue.  The Ruby parser treats an expression like `foo = 123` as a local variable assignment.  In order to call an accessor method, you need to prefix `self.` to remove the ambiguity and execute the assignment method.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) is it one of the way to prevent from name conflict. say, the parameter is called buyer, i can do `self.buyer = buyer`